# How to accept user inputs as arguments for a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a tax calculator using HTML and Javascript. It needs to accept two user inputs ("Total owed" and "Your payment") and calculate what percentage "Your payment" is of "Total owed". Then they should be displayed within the "answerParagraph" tag. What is the best way to do this?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="getPercentage">
  <div id="total">
    Total owed:
    <input id="totalInput" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="payment">
    Your payment:
    <input id="paymentInput" type="text">
  </div>
  <button onclick="handlers.getPercentage()">Get percentage</button>
</div>
  <div>
    <p id="answerParagraph">
    </p>
  </div>

<script>
var taxes = {
  getPercentage: function(total, payment) {
   var percentage = (Math.floor((payment / total) * 100));
   },
  }

var handlers = {
  getPercentage: function() {
    var totalInput = document.getElementById('totalInput');
    var paymentInput = document.getElementById('paymentInput');
    var answer = taxes.getPercentage(totalInput.value, paymentInput.value);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the answer from taxes.getPercentage function

```
getPercentage: function (total, payment) {
            var percentage = (Math.floor((payment / total) * 100));
            return percentage;
        }
```

And display in your answerParagraph. So, in handlers.getPercentage :

```
...    
var answer = taxes.getPercentage(totalInput.value, paymentInput.value);
                answerParagraph.innerHTML = answer;
```

Answer (score 0):

the following modified code should work

```js
var taxes = {
  getPercentage: function(total, payment) {
    var percentage = (Math.floor((payment / total) * 100));
    return percentage
  },
}

var handlers = {
  getPercentage: function() {
    var totalInput = document.getElementById('totalInput');
    var paymentInput = document.getElementById('paymentInput');
    var answer = taxes.getPercentage(totalInput.value, paymentInput.value);
    document.getElementById('answerParagraph').innerHTML = answer
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="getPercentage">
    <div id="total">
      Total owed:
      <input id="totalInput" type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="payment">
      Your payment:
      <input id="paymentInput" type="text">
    </div>
    <button onclick="handlers.getPercentage()">Get percentage</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p id="answerParagraph">
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the button if you trigger the `calcpercentage()` function by the `keyup`-event on either of the two input fields:

```js
// define shorthand notation byId(id):
const byId=id=>document.getElementById(id);

// delegated event binding: affects INPUT elements only
byId('getPercentage').addEventListener('keyup',function(ev){
 if(ev.target.tagName!='INPUT') return false;
     byId('answerParagraph').innerHTML=
    (byId('paymentInput').value*100 /
     byId('totalInput').value).toFixed(2)+"%";
});

// trigger event manually ...
byId('totalInput').dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup',{bubbles:true}));
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="getPercentage">
    <div id="total">
      Total owed:
      <input id="totalInput" type="text" value="1000">
    </div>
    <div id="payment">
      Your payment:
      <input id="paymentInput" type="text" value="25">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p id="answerParagraph">
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```